# Running the same run configuration in eclipse multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, run-configuration

I have a particular run configuration in Eclipse for a simulation that I would like to run 100 times or so. Is there a way that I can do this without physically sitting at my computer and hitting run over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bash script that runs the class 100 times.

```
for i in {1..100} 
   do 
     java "class path"
   done
```

Assumption that OS is linux